# How to add event in fullcalendar?

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I'm not a PHP freak, but I can understand it.

I want to use fullcalendar ([this example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/external-dragging.html))

I have read the full documentation.
I have read the full 43 page here by tag fullcalendar
but can't find my answer.

Very simple,
How to add a event when I drag into a date?

The script read from a JSON file, but how to write to the JSON?

The JS file from fullcalendar:

```
$(function()
{
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#external-events ul li').each(function() 
    {
        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };
        
        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
        
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable(
        {
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag,
            start: function() { if (typeof mainYScroller != 'undefined') mainYScroller.disable(); },
            stop: function() { if (typeof mainYScroller != 'undefined') mainYScroller.enable(); }
        });
        
    });

    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        events: rootPath + "/admin/ajax/calendarEvents.json",
        drop: function(date, allDay) 
        {
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            
            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
            
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
            
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the html

```
    <div class="widget widget-inverse">
    
        <!-- Widget heading -->
        <div class="widget-head">
            <h3 class="heading">Draggable Events</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- // Widget heading END -->
        
        <div class="widget-body">
        
            <!-- Events list -->
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <li class="glyphicons move"><i></i> My Event 1</li>
                <li class="glyphicons move"><i></i> My Event 2</li>
                <li class="glyphicons move"><i></i> My Event 3</li>
                <li class="glyphicons move"><i></i> My Event 4</li>
                <li class="glyphicons move"><i></i> My Event 5</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Events list END -->
            
            <label for="drop-remove" class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="drop-remove" /> 
                remove after drop
            </label>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you have the function drop there right, basically add an "alert()" inside that drop function. If it's working then please let me know :)

Comment: So what you want is after dropping the event you want to save it to a json file? If that's the case you use the [eventDrop](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) instead of drop callback and in there make a ajax call to your server. If you need further explanation let me know.

Comment: @Aljie , yes, it drop it , but don't save it

Comment: @HenriqueC. Yes, that's what i want. but i have read it, but can't make it, the explanation is not for "beginner" if you want to help , it will be great thanks a lot .

Comment: i already done what you want with your calendar, if that's the case. did you try the "alert('im drop');" inside your drop function?

Comment: @Aljie nope, i'm very newbee i don't know how or what . :(  thx for helping me

Comment: please try it, and if something or if it's alerting then we can move now to the second step.

Answer (score 0):

look at this page: [draggable events](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html)

Look up the source code and you'll see the drop function

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        **drop**: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, the drop do it from beginning, i want to save it into the Json file.file.

Comment: @DaveTitan, I don't think that you can save it to a file but you can surely use $.ajax to send the data back to your backend and save it there.

Comment: Yes, absolutly, but How is the question.

Comment: which parameters (args) do you need to save?

Comment: =>  ID ( Auto I ), Title and Start that's it

Comment: hi Dave, you need to save these variables into some tabels. Query the tables and JSON encode the result and output it.